# Use Sinatra redirect in ternary operator

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Does any one know why

```
saved ? redirect '/success' : erb :signup
```

Throws the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
```

While this does not?

```
saved ? redirect('/success') : erb(:signup)
```

Comment: Parsing ambiguity, obviously.

Comment: Thanks. Ruby syntax is just a bit over my head :-(